# Calculating daily yields with a different compounding interest

Tags: compound-interest, apy

For simplicity's sake, suppose I have an investment that earns 1% daily return on average.

The following day, that 1% earning is immediately rolled over into an account that earns 10% yearly compounding daily.

So suppose I had $1000 as an initial investment, by day two I would have $1010. That $10 would then be rolled into the 10% APY account. This cycle would repeat every day.

How would I calculate the ending yield and total overall APY % if I plugged it into a spreadsheet?

Comment: "This cycle would repeat every day." What exactly repeats every day?

Comment: Earn 1% initial account, take 1% earned to transfer to 10% account.

Comment: I'd break it down into pieces: cell A1=364; cell A2 = $1000; cell A3=A2*1.01; cell A4=A3*1.10*(A1/365).  That tells you how much you'd make on the first $1000.

Comment: Do the same in row B, except cell A2 = 363, since it's the next day.  Repeat 361 more times.  Then sum up column 4.

Comment: This presumes the banks are open 365 days per year, and it's not a leap year.  Adjust that as you see fit.

Comment: Is there a way to do that using functions/equations so I can just plug it into a calculator without having to have 365 rows in my sheet? These numbers will change.

Comment: I don't know.  *Copy and paste* should make the grunt work easier, and there's nothing to stop you from putting 1% in cell `A5`, and 10% in cell `A6`, then instead of `A3=A2*1.01`, you say `A3=A2*(1+$A$5)`.  Similarly, `A4=A3*(1+$A$6)*(A1/365)`.

Comment: That way, when the interest rate changes, you alter `A5` and  `A6`, all the numbers change.  Remember also that you can use Series Fill to generate the numbers 364 thru 1.

Answer (score 1):

"*suppose I had $1000 as an initial investment, by day two I would have $1010. That $10 would then be rolled into the 10% APY account. This cycle would repeat every day.*"

It sounds like you are effectively putting $10 into a 10% (let's say daily) account, every day.

```
a = 10
r = 0.1
```

Totalling up the balance `x` over days.  (Assuming the $10 would be transferred at the *end* of the day, after accumulating from the $1000.)

```
start  x = 0
day 1  x = x*(1 + r) + a = 10
day 2  x = x*(1 + r) + a = 21
day 3  x = x*(1 + r) + a = 33.1
```

In a mathematical formula

```
n = 3

(a ((1 + r)^n - 1))/r = 33.1
```

In Excel

```
A1 = 10
A2 = 0.1
A3 = 3

=A1*(POWER(1+A2,A3)-1)/A2
```

Comment: you assume A3 and A2 to be in years, but the poster wanted a 10% APY. you will need to do something like `A2 = 0.1/365` (for compounding every day of the year) or `A2 = 0.1/252` (for stock market trading days) for the poster to get a more accurate description of what they want.

Comment: @rhavelka Indeed, `r` and `A2` should be `0.1/365` or `1/252`.  `n` and `A3` are in days though, as intended.

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit to my comment and accidentally lost that A3 was in days.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Future Value of Annuity](https://exceljet.net/formula/future-value-of-annuity) function built into excel. You can set it up with the following example of 10% APY compounding daily, 5 days of compounding, and 1% of the $1000 added every single day

```
A1 = 0.1/365
A2 = 5
A3 = 1000 * 0.01

=FV(A1, A2, -A3)
```

This will give a final value of $50.03 in your account after 5 days which you can easily check against your spreadsheet.

**Note 1**: A3 has to be negative to receive a positive answer. I always view it as if you are putting in a positive $10 you are paying someone else. If you are putting in a -$10 someone is paying you. (In this case it is you who is paying you).

**Note 2**: This is excel using a pure math function which means it will carry more decimals than your financial institution will have, so you will have some rounding error.